# Installing PowerShell module in linux silently /quiet

Tags: linux, powershell

I am trying to install a powershell module in linux using install-module and doesn't want to see the progress

I've already set the $ProgressPreference = "SilentlyContinue" but doesn't seem to help.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text - it's much more useful to include it as text

Answer (score 0):

When you’d like to install modules for all users from the PowerShellGet repository, you need Administrator privileges. On PowerShell Core on Linux, you can use the command “sudo” to enable Administrator privileges, and run PowerShell. Just make sure you specify the command in braces.

This would install the module AzureRM.NetCore from the PowerShell Gallery with administrator privileges for all users on PowerShell Core on Linux:

sudo powershell -Command {Install-Module -Name AzureRM.Netcore}